# C# timestamp comparison by string.Compare

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Will using `string.Compare(timeA,TimeB)` always return -1 given that:

`timeA` is a timestamp that happened before `timeB`

and

both are in this format: `12/27/2012 00:59:06` aka `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` via `DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 5):

Well yes. Why would you *expect* that to work? If you want to sort by *time*, parse them both into `DateTime` values and compare those. You're comparing them *as strings* so they'll be compared lexicographically. Of course if your timestamp format was `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` or something similar, you *could* compare them lexicographically - but your current format just *isn't* designed for sorting.

You *could* write an `IComparer<string>` which did the parsing each time, but you'd be much better off just parsing the values as early as you could, and keeping them in their more native representation (`DateTime`) for as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your `Timestamps` as a `string`. Just use `<` and `>` with [`DateTime.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

```
value timea = DateTime.Parse(timeA);
value timeb = DateTime.Parse(timeB);

if( timeA > timeB )
{
  // your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
string.Compare(timeA, timeB)
```

to work, `timeA` and `timeB` must be strings. And strings are compared alphabetically, so a string beginning with a 1, like *'12/27/2012'* will always be smaller that a string that begins with a 2, like *'2/27/2010'*.

In order to compare dates, you could use:

```
DateTime.Compare(timeA, timeB)
```

where `timeA` and `timeB` are `DateTime`'s. If, as you say, they are both generated in your code, just avoid using a `.ToString()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Compare(string strA, string strB);
```

Returns:
        //     A 32-bit signed integer that indicates the lexical relationship between the
        //     two comparands.Value Condition Less than zero  strA is less than strB. Zero
        //     strA equals strB. Greater than zero strA is greater than strB.